# unexpected linebreak when using `\nameref` in marginpar

Tags: cross-referencing, line-breaking, marginpar

I have an unexpected linebreak in my `\marginpar` and don't know where it comes from. It appears right in the middle of the `\nameref`... Does anyone see the mistake?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{lipsum}

% customize Marginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in} 
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft\footnotesize #1]%
    {\raggedright\footnotesize \textit{#1}}}

\usepackage{nameref}        %Kann auch mit Namen des Kapitels referenzieren

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Anforderungsdokument erstellen} \label{Anforderungenableiten}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \chapter{bla}
        \marginpar{siehe auch Abschnitt \ref{Anforderungenableiten} \nameref{Anforderungenableiten}}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: marginpar]

The word "erstellen" actually should fit on the previous line...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might I suggest the use of `\autoref`? It is bit more flexible. you'll need to load the `hyperref`-package

Comment: You may, but I will stick to this process, since I used it for my entire document now. Maybe next time, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard `\raggedright` does not dissuade TeX from giving lots of white space at the end of lines, however TeX does have demerits for hyphenating the penultimate line of a paragraph, so it ends up making it more desirable to force the extra line so that the hyphenation is not the penultimate line.

The `\RaggedRight` version has less flexible glue at the end of line and that is enough to keep things more balanced.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% customize Marginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in} 
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\RaggedLeft\footnotesize #1]%
    {\RaggedRight\footnotesize \textit{#1}}}

\usepackage{nameref}        %Kann auch mit Namen des Kapitels referenzieren

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Anforderungsdokument erstellen} \label{Anforderungenableiten}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \chapter{bla}
        \marginpar{siehe auch Abschnitt \ref{Anforderungenableiten} \nameref{Anforderungenableiten}}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and your decent explanation.

Comment: Imho one should also add `\finalhyphendemerits=0` in the marginpar. It doesn't make much sense to make it harder then necessary in such short text.

Comment: Do you mean in addition to Davids answer? And where to add this cmd, @UlrikeFischer? In the preamble of the document or in the customizing marginpar cmd?

Comment: @Eric: In your example it would actually help without David's code. Put it behind the (both) \footnotesize in the marginpar. (You can also put it in the preamble but then it will affect the whole document.).

Comment: Since 2020, the `\raggedright` code contains `\finalhyphendemerits=0`, so `\raggedright` should work just as well as `\RaggedRight` now.